# How to avoid form submission in Django on pressing enter key?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I wish to prevent form submission on pressing enter in django. I have searched over internet, and found jquery/javascript based solution. I have tried to use the below js snippet but it is not working. Can anyone help me out here? I am using Django==2.2 version.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: make sure you `return false;` and addEventListener on 'keydown'

Comment: @MaheshC.Regmi Thanks a lot, now it is working